# VHDL BCD to 7 Segment Display

Tags: vhdl, bcd

I'm very new to VHDL and there is a problem I can't quite get my head around.

I am trying to display a 12 bit BCD onto 3 7-segment displays. However, I am at a lost on how to split the 12 bit BCD into 3 digits. I am using this tutorial as a guide

http://vhdlguru.blogspot.com/2010/04/8-bit-binary-to-bcd-converter-double.html

Displaying a 4 bit BCD to a 7-segment is straightforward enough, but I am lost if more digits are present.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To display one digit to the seven segment display (SSD), you need 4 bits of BCD.

To display three digits to the SSD, you need 3x 4 = 12 bits.

Not all of the 4 bits per digit are used, however.

In the example you refer to, bcd(3 downto 0) is used for the first digit, bcd(7 downto 4) is used for the second, and bcd(11 downto 8) is used for the third.